# WQL Like statement & syntax

Tags: c#, wmi, wql

I've seen atleast two other questions regarding WMI but none had an answer to my question, so here it is;

I was experimenting with the `WMI` interface in my code. Basically this is what i have right now and it works. But it seems to me i could write it more efficiently:

`public bool GetUsbStateById(string id)
    {
      bool returnValue = false;`

```
  try
  {
    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery();
    query.QueryString = string.Format("Select * From Win32_PnPDevice");
    ManagementObjectSearcher mySearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

    List<ManagementObject> results = (from ManagementObject mo in mySearcher.Get().AsParallel()
                                      where mo["SystemElement"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains(id.ToUpper())
                                      select mo).ToList();

    if (results.Count > 0)
      returnValue = true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // TODO: implement logging
  }

  return returnValue;
}
```

So what happens here is that i get a list of `ManagementObjects` from the `ManagementObjectSearcher`. This works fine and also returns the exact results as i expect it to work.

But it seems redundant to me. Because, first i get the whole list, and then filter it. But because it uses `WQL` to fill the list, i assumed that i could implement something like this:

`query.QueryString = string.Format("Select * From Win32_PnPDevice where SystemElement Like '%{0}%'",id);`

this keeps throwing an `exception` that the query is not correct.

so i tried this instead:

`query.QueryString = string.Format("Select SystemElement From Win32_PnPDevice);`

This works as well, so next i tried `Win32_PnPDevice.SystemElement`, but this didn't work either.

any examples i looked at on the internet showed something like this

`Select * From Win32_Service 
Where Name Like "%SQL%"`

but c# can't parse the double quotes that surround the `%SQL%` statement there, using an the `\` escape character yielded no results either.

To test my code and the code posted below i used the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) from Microsoft

Comment: so apparently microsoft didn't implement the like operator for ref classes as discussed here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/winserverpowershell/thread/24981775-e105-42a8-8313-b0b86972f6c3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to run [like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) query in `WMI` then you can use below example:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
              string strSearchText="win";
              string strSearchQuery=string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service where Name like '%{0}%'",strSearchText);
              ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",strSearchQuery  );

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Win32_Service instance");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
            }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**But** you can not apply `like` query on `Win32_PNPDevice` as [discussed](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/winserverpowershell/thread/24981775-e105-42a8-8313-b0b86972f6c3)

Comment: i tried using that with my code, but as i stated before that doesn't seem to work, even though i except it to work. the code i used is the following (taken from the WMI code creator from microsoft)

Comment: why have you removed your search query

Comment: yes i tried your code, and it did work. i removed the query because i could get in the right format. give me a minute and i'll add it again

Comment: i tried using that with my code, but as i stated before that doesn't seem to work, even though i except it to work. the code i used is the following (taken from the WMI code creator from microsoft) 
try
{
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPDevice where SystemElement like '%HDAUDIO%'"); 

            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {

            }

my apollogies for the format

Comment: the error i get is that the query is not in the correct syntax. i assume this has something to do with the like statement. because when i replace the asterisk with SystemElement it parses correctly and returns values

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24711/discussion-between-arshad-and-wterbeek)